# Incircle of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, plane-geometry

[image]

In the above image, it says $$AE = \frac{bc}{c+a}$$ and $$AF = \frac{bc}{a+b}$$ But $AE$ and $AF$ are tangents from $A$ to the incircle. As tangents on a circle from a given point are equal, $AE=AF$ which implies $b=c$ which is absurd. What is wrong here?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $D$, $E$, $F$ are the points where the angle bisectors meet the sides of the triangle. They are not *usually* the points of tangency with the incircle. When the text discusses equilateral triangles, the points "become" the points of tangency.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what book is it?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Coordinate Geometry For JEE by Dr S K Goyal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AE$ and $AF$ are not tangents. The angle bisector is not usually perpendicular to the opposite side. If that would be the case for all sides, then you have an equilateral triangle. It's easy to see in the figure that $AD$ is not perpendicular to $BC$